# virt-viewer slower than virt-manager when viewing

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virt-manager

I've got a thin client server in which I have a few VM's for users under KVM which I manage through virt-manager.

What I've noticed is if I start a VM guest on a thin client using the command 'virt-viewer ' then the guest is painfully slow to move around. However if on the same thin client I start the same guest VM through virt-manager it's fast.

What are the differences here?

Can I view a VM without having the user load up virt-manager and double click on their VM?

Should I be looking at using splice in virt-viewer instead of VNC which is what I currently use?

Comment: Instead of using virt-manager, you can start VMs interactively or from scripts via virsh. Additionally, through virsh you can configure certain VMs to automatically start when the libvirt service is started.

Comment: Just to clarify I have no problem starting VMs, just viewing them.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely start using spice, especially if the guest supports QXL, it is much faster than VNC and the picture quality is pretty much what you will get from a normal video card (you'll be able to watch multimedia in the remote session)